# Group over dynamic date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a table with IDs, dates and values. I want to always merge the records based on the ID that are within a 90 day window. In the example below, these are the rows marked in the same color.

[image: origin]

The end result should look like this:

[image: endresult]

The entry with the RowId 1 opens the 90 days window for the ID 133741. RowId 2 and 3 are in this window and should therefore be aggregated together with RowId 1.

RowId 4 would be in a 90 day window with 2 and 3, but since it is outside the window for 1, it should no longer be aggregated with them but should be considered as the start of a new 90 day window. Since there are no other entries in this window, it remains as a single line.

The date for line 5 is clearly outside the 90 day window of the other entries and is therefore also aggregated individually. Just like line 6, since this is a different ID.

Below some example code:

```
create table #Table(RowId int, ID nvarchar(255) , Date date, Amount numeric(19,1));
insert into #Table values


(1,'133742',    '2021-07-30',   1.00    ),
(2,'133742',    '2021-08-05',   3.00    ),
(3,'133742',    '2021-08-25',   10.00   ),
(4,'133742',    '2021-11-01',   7.00    ),
(5,'133742',    '2022-08-25',   11.00   ),
(6,'133769',    '2021-11-13',   9.00    );
```

I tried with windowfunctions and CTEs but I could'nt find a way to include all my requirements

Answer (score 3):

With the window function `first_value() over()` we calculate the distance in days divided by 90 to get the derived `Grp`

**Example**

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,Grp = datediff(day,first_value(Date) over (partition by id order by date) ,date) / 90
 from #Table
 )
 Select ID 
       ,Date = min(date)
       ,Amount = sum(Amount)
 From  cte
 Group By ID,Grp
 Order by ID,min(date)
```

**Results**

```
ID      Date        Amount
133742  2021-07-30  14.0
133742  2021-11-01  7.0
133742  2022-08-25  11.0
133769  2021-11-13  9.0
```

Comment: AMAZING. I didn't expect it to be solved in so few lines. I also didn't work with first_value() before so I'll look more into this. Thank you!

Comment: @G.Maen Always happy to help.   The window functions are well worth your discovery time.  They can be invaluable.

Comment: I just realized, that it does not totally respect all criteria. Because all the 90days windows for one ID are set by the very first entry, If I had an entry (7,'133742',    '2022-01-29',   7.00    ) for example it would not be put together in a 90 days window with row 4. Which it should, as row 4 should set the start of the new 90 days window and the additional row 7 would be in that window (89 days difference).

What needed to be done would be to kind of reuse the date from row 4 to begin the new 90 days window.
I wonder if this could only be done recursively?!